# Is there a Python library for OpenStreetMap Overpass API?

Tags: python, api, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have found this API for the main OpenStreetMap API http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PythonOsmApi. Is there a similar Python API for overpass-api?

Comment: I just stumbled into [overpass-api-python-wrapper](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper). I did not use it yet though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python module for implementing the Overpass API for querying OpenStreetMap data. Check this out:

[OpenStreetMap OverPass API Python Module](https://launchpad.net/osmxapi)

However i must **warn** you that this is not maintained, but, as far i know, there exists no other API.

Comment: This python module seems to support only a subset of the Overpass API language. Furthermore it also uses the regular API and allows bulk-queries which are clearly against the [API usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy). So expect to get blocked when using it the wrong way.